# Change number of occurrences in list

Tags: python

I have a list of lists. The last item in each list is the QTY. What I need to do is change this list so that if the first 3 items are already in the list, add 1 to the qty item in the list. Here is what I have so far, but after 1 becomes 2, now its not matching.

```
x = [[1,2,3,1], ['x', 'y', 'z',1], ['a', 'bv', 'sdf',1], ['x', 'y', 'z',1], ['x', 'y', 'z',1]]

new_list = []
for item in x:
    if item not in new_list:
        new_list.append(item)
    else:
        index = new_list.index(item)
        qty = new_list[index][3]
        qty += 1
        item[3] = qty
        new_list[index] = item

print(new_list)
```

Output of the above code:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 1], ['x', 'y', 'z', 2], ['a', 'bv', 'sdf', 1], ['x', 'y', 'z', 1]]
```

What the output needs to look like:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 1], ['x', 'y', 'z', 3], ['a', 'bv', 'sdf', 1]]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dict to keep track of the count:

```
x = [[1,2,3,1],
     ['x', 'y', 'z',1],
     ['a', 'bv', 'sdf',1],
     ['x', 'y', 'z',1],
     ['x', 'y', 'z',1]]

count = {}
for item in x:
    key = tuple(item[:3])  # dict keys can't be lists
    if key in count:
        count[key] += item[3]
    else:
        count[key] = item[3]

new_list = [list(key) + [val] for key, val in count.items()]

print(new_list)
```

which outputs:

```
c:\srv\tmp> py -3.10 listoccur.py
[[1, 2, 3, 1], ['x', 'y', 'z', 3], ['a', 'bv', 'sdf', 1]]
```

Comment: `count[key] += 1` might not give the expected result. The fourth element might not be `1` always.

Comment: No problem! Then no need for my answer anymore :D

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same idea as @thebjorn, but he was quicker. Here is another implementation:

```
import collections

x = [[1,2,3,1], ['x', 'y', 'z',1], ['a', 'bv', 'sdf',1], ['x', 'y', 'z',1], ['x', 'y', 'z',1]]

summary = collections.defaultdict(int)
for a,b,c,qty in x:
    summary[(a,b,c)] += qty 
result = [[*k, v] for k, v in summary.items()]

print(result)
# [[1, 2, 3, 1], ['x', 'y', 'z', 3], ['a', 'bv', 'sdf', 1]]
```

Comment: I like your version better :-)

Comment: What's the advantage over `Counter`?

Comment: @KellyBundy there is none, except perhaps pedagogically it may be preferable to show the algorithm..?  Feel free to add an answer using Counter (I'll give you an upvote)

Comment: Hmm, the only thing that would change is that `defaultdict(int)` would become `Counter()`. I just keep seeing people use the former quite often and always wonder why they don't use the latter, as that seems more straightforward to me.

Comment: @KellyBundy I see `Counter` as a replacement for a loop with `... += 1`, but I'm not sure it the quantity here is always 1 as in the example.